# How to get values of decoded JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{"senderDetails":[{"status":"failed","senderid":"0","message":"Kindly upgrade your account to use this service."}]}
```

Above is my JSON data. I used `json_decode()` function to decode, but I don't know how to echo the values of each object separately in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you want to print the senderid :

```
<?php
$var = '{"senderDetails":[{"status":"failed","senderid":"0","message":"Kindly upgrade your account to use this service."}]}';

$decoded = json_decode($var);

var_dump($decoded);
echo($decoded->senderDetails[0]->senderid);

?>
```

It's important to use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on those kind of variables to understand how to access them properly.

Comment: tell me how will is use var_dumb and whats its use

Comment: var_dump is a function that will display every strutured informations of a variable.
Use it like this :

var_dump($my_variable)

This way, you will see that your variable is an object containing an array etc..

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object : i am getting this error

Comment: if (isset($decoded)) {
 echo($decoded->senderDetails[0]->senderid);
 echo 0;
}else {
 echo 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo **all** values you can loop through the array like so:

```
foreach($your_array as $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

However if you want to output a specific element you can just do:

```
echo( $your_array->object->value );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$json_array = json_decode($json,true) //If you add true you get an array as Response
$value = $json_array["senderDetails"]["status"]; // Example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to an array and echo the variables this way

```
$json_data = '{"senderDetails":[{"status":"failed","senderid":"0","message":"Kindly upgrade your account to use this service."}]}';
$decoded = json_decode($json_data,true);

echo "Status = ".($decoded["senderDetails"][0]["status"]);
echo "<br />";
echo "Senderid = ".($decoded["senderDetails"][0]["senderid"]);
echo "<br />";
echo "Message = ".($decoded["senderDetails"][0]["message"]);
```